Orbital tool is not integrated in my react typescript app
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>React Typescript Template</title>
    
        <script>
            (function(o,r,b,i,t,a,l){
            o[r]||(t=o[r]=function(){i.push(arguments)},t._t=new Date,t._v=1,i=t._q=[])
            })(window,'orbital');
            // orbital('identify', {{user-id}}, {email: {{email}}}); // This line only needed if recruiting from a specific segment
            </script>
            <!-- Note the space-id in the URL below. -->
            <script src="https://client.useorbital.com/api/account/{{space_id}}/client.js" async></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
    </body>
    
    </html>
    
    
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
    import styled from 'styled-components';
    import { Rating } from '@material-ui/lab';
    import { Button } from '@material-ui/core';
    import { CallRatingRequestPayload, makeRatingCall } from '../../services/call-rating.service';
    import useUser from '../../hooks/useUser';
    import UserAvatar from '../common/UserAvatar';
    import { useCall } from '../../customer-call-sdk';
    
    const StyledCustomerRating = styled.div`
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        overflow: auto;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        padding: 1.2rem;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        .header-style {
            font-weight: 700;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 2.75rem;
        }
    
        .avatar-container {
            display: block;
            align-self: center;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            .avatar {
                width: 130px;
                height: 130px;
                color: #bac0c6;
                background-color: #bac0c6;
            }
            .avatar svg {
                width: 100px;
                height: 100px;
                color: black;
            }
        }
    
        .interpreter-name {
            font-weight: 600;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 1.25rem;
            color: var(--text-primary);
            margin-bottom: 0.25rem;
        }
    
        .NRPCD-register-number {
            margin-top: -10px;
            font-weight: 200;
            font-size: 1.3rem;
            text-align: center;
            color: #1c1c1c;
        }
    
        .call-duration {
            font-weight: 200;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 1rem;
            color: #1c1c1c;
            margin-top: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 15px;
        }
    
        .Horizontal-line {
            width: 100%;
            border: 1px solid #efefef;
        }
    
        .rate-div-box {
            display: block;
            align-self: center;
            margin-bottom: 1.7rem;
            margin-top: 1.7rem;
        }
    
        .button-area-box {
            padding: 20px;
            margin-top: 100px;
        }
    
        .rate-button-style {
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #00934a;
            border-radius: 300px;
            color: white;
            line-height: 40px;
            text-align: center;
            margin-bottom: 1rem;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        Button:disabled {
            background-color: #bce3cd;
        }
    
        .skip-button-style {
            color: black;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            margin-top: 10px;
            cursor: pointer;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 1.2rem;
        }
    
        .text-area {
        }
    `;
    
    const StyledRating = styled(Rating)`
        color: #00934a;
        font-size: 4.5rem;
    `;
    
    export interface CustomerRatingProps extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement> {}
    
    const CustomerRating: React.FC<CustomerRatingProps> = ({ ...props }) => {
        const user = useUser();
        const call = useCall();
        const { ratingDetail } = call;
        const [rating, setRating] = useState<number>(0);
        const [isRating, setIsRating] = useState<boolean>(false);
    
        // useEffect(()=>{
        //     if(user?.uuid){
        //         console.log('Identifying user with orbital', user.uuid, user.email)
        //         orbital('identify', user.uuid, {email:user.email})
        //     }
        // },[user])
    
        const createRating = async () => {
            const ratingDetailForPayload = Object.create(ratingDetail);
            call.closeRating();
            if (ratingDetailForPayload) {
                const payload: CallRatingRequestPayload = {
                    userId: user?.uuid as string,
                    requestId: ratingDetailForPayload.requestId as string,
                    rating,
                    comment: '',
                    callQualityComment: '',
                    callQualityRating: rating,
                    providerId: ratingDetailForPayload.providerName as string,
                };
                await makeRatingCall(payload);
            }
        };
    
        const skipRating = async() => {
            call.closeRating();   
            console.log("Before orbital trigger")
           
            orbital('trigger','<discovery_id>');
            console.log("after orbital trigger", orbital)   
        };
    
        return (
            <StyledCustomerRating {...props}>
                <h1 className="header-style">How was your call experience?</h1>
    
                <div className="avatar-container">
                    <UserAvatar className="avatar" />
                </div>
    
                <div className="text-area">
                    <div className="interpreter-name">{ratingDetail?.interpreterName}</div>
                    <div className="NRPCD-register-number">{ratingDetail?.interpreterNRPCDNumber}</div>
                    <div className="call-duration">{`${ratingDetail?.callDuration} minutes today`}</div>
                </div>
    
                <div className="Horizontal-line" />
                <div className="rate-div-box">
                    <StyledRating
                        precision={1}
                        size="large"
                        max={5}
                        onChange={(event, value) => {
                            setRating(value as number);
                            if ((value as number) > 0) {
                                setIsRating(true);
                            } else {
                                setIsRating(false);
                            }
                        }}
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="button-area-box">
                    <Button
                        fullWidth
                        color="primary"
                        variant="contained"
                        onClick={createRating}
                        className="rate-button-style"
                        disabled={!isRating}
                    >
                        Rate
                    </Button>
    
                    <div className="skip-button-style" onClick={skipRating}>
                        Skip
                    </div>
                </div>
            </StyledCustomerRating>
        );
    };
    
    export default CustomerRating;
    

I am trying to integrate the orbital SDK into my react typescript application. I am using tracking snippet in index.html file to integrate the orbital. Above in skip rating function I was trying to use the orbital, I am also using the actual discovery id here but still nothing happens. What I actually want is when I skip the rating then a pop up should display which orbital provide in initial prompt but in my case nothing happened. Just wanted to know Am I missing something here while doing integration?
 https://useorbital.com/docs/client-sdk

